# Problemas al crear bien un pdf creado con fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

mi problema es que al crear el pdf la tabla donde lo creo me muestra los datos cortados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la imagen en servicios realizados me muestra los datos correlativos y yo quiero que me los muestre uno separado de otro hacia abajo

extracto de codigo que crea la tabla

```
    function cabecera($cabecera){
    $this->SetXY(35,105);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    foreach($cabecera as $columna)
    {
        $this->Cell(55,7,$columna,1, 2 , 'L' ) ;
    }
}

function datos($datos){

    $this->SetXY(90,105);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    foreach ($datos as $columna)
    {   $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['estado']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['id']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['nombre']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['rut']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['email']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['phone']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['mensaje']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['servicio']),'TRB',2,'L' );

    }
}

//El método tabla integra a los métodos cabecera y datos
function tabla($cabecera,$datos){
    $this->cabecera ($cabecera) ;
    $this->datos($datos);
}


    }//fin clase PDF
   ?>
```

Y con este extracto de codigo los extraigo de mi base de datos para crear el pdf

```
   public function seleccionar_persona($id)
  {
    $q = "select id , nombre, rut,
                 email, phone,
                 direccion,mensaje,estado,servicio  from contribuyente
                 where
                 id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Puedes revisar este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542244/wrap-text-in-fpdf-in-php) de la página en ingles de stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un nuevo bucle que haga un explode de los servicios y continuara poniendo celdas.

El problema es que veo que no los tienes separado en base de datos de ninguna manera. por lo hace la tarea muy difícil. 
ha la hora de guardar separarlos con un carácter raro (;#), y haz el `explode(';', servicios);`

```
function datos($datos){
    $this->SetXY(90,105);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    foreach ($datos as $columna)
    {   $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['estado']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['id']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['nombre']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['rut']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['email']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['phone']),'TRB',2,'L' );
        $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($columna['mensaje']),'TRB',2,'L' );

        $serv_tmp = explode(";",$columna['servicio']);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($serv_tmp); ++$i) {

            $this->Cell(80,7,utf8_decode($serv_tmp[$i]),'TRB',2,'L' );
        }
    }
}
```